# how to make a venn diagram of the following

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I need to do a venn diagram of $$X^\complement \cap  (Y\cup Z) $$
I know that I start with the union of $Y$ and $Z$, having all of circles $Y$ and $Z$ colored, then I take the intersection with $X$ which would only be the part of the circle that touch $X$ with the circles $X$ and $Y$ and to take the complement (part where I am confused) would it be the rest of circle $X$ that has previously not drawn and the rest of the universe without counting the previous work of $Y$ and $Z$?

Answer (score 3):

Imagine the Venn diagram of the sets $X, Y, Z$ is represented as below.

[image]

Then $Y\cup Z$ is represented as

[image]

and $X^C$ is represented as

[image]

And finally, $X^C \cap (Y\cup Z)$ is the intersection of the two diagrams above and is represented as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take the complement before the intersection.  It should be the parts of $Y$ and $Z$ that are *not* in $X$.

Comment: so the final answer would be the parts of Y and Z that are not in X along with the rest of the universe or just the parts of Y and Z that are not in X?

Comment: Just the parts of $Y$ and $Z$ not in $X$.  Read it as "the parts not in $X$ that are also in either $Y$ or $Z$."